# Is there a quick way to find the correct coordinate parameters for get_overlapping?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

it's pretty tedious working out the dimensions of an image then halving it and adding it on every time I want to check whether something is overlapping.

Comment: can you provide a [mcve] that illustrates the problem you are having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely want to use `bbox`.

This '[returns the bounding box for all matching items](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.bbox-method)', i.e. the rectangle outline of the picture you want to get the coordinates of.

```
coords = canvas.bbox(item)
```

or

```
coords = canvas.bbox("itemtag")
```

In the case of multiple items with the same tag, it will use the first item given that tag.